# Can I use ArcGIS REST-API "applyEdits" to update Feature-Layer as an authenticated user?

Tags: node.js, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, esri-oss

I'm using nodeJS to edit my Feature-Layer using REST API. My intention is to:

1. Update my layer using Firebase Cloud-Functions
2. Share my layer publicly
3. But keep my layer non-editable for unauthorised users
4. I want to use my API-Key for authentication.

**My problem:** If I edit my feature definition to `"capabilities" : "Create, Update, Delete"` as mentioned [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/services-reference/enterprise/apply-edits-feature-service-layer-.htm), then any unauthorised user can edit my layer, while if I don't, I get:

> [
> 'This operation is not supported.',
> 'Unable to add the features.',
> 'This operation is not supported.'
> ]

Authentication is declered [in the documentation](https://esri.github.io/arcgis-rest-js/api/feature-layer/applyEdits/).

My code:

```
require("cross-fetch/polyfill");
require("isomorphic-form-data");
const featureLayer = require('@esri/arcgis-rest-feature-layer');
const auth = require('@esri/arcgis-rest-auth');

const apiKey = new auth.ApiKey({key: 'some key...'});
featureLayer.applyEdits({
    url: "https://services3.arcgis.com/someID/arcgis/rest/services/someName/FeatureServer/0",
    adds: [{
      geometry: { x: 120, y: 45 },
      attributes: { indexCity: "alive" }
    }],
    authentication: apiKey
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.response.error.details));
```

I'm running my code using `node example.js` in terminal.

### How can I define appleEdits only for me as authenticated user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to make your edits to a private feature layer (that's editable), and then have a public (non-editable) view of that feature layer.

- https://www.esri.com/about/newsroom/arcuser/protect-your-editable-feature-data-from-the-public/
- https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/manage-data/create-hosted-views.htm